# Excel VBA - How to store an image in an add-in

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon, office-addins

In my add-in I have created a gallery on a custom Excel ribbon with specific images inside that the user can choose to use in their document.

These specific images need to be stored in the add-in and not in an external folder, so that no matter where the add-in is installed the user will have access to the images. Currently I have stored the images on a hidden worksheet in the add-in.

My question is, is the this the best way to do this or is there another more foolproof way of storing/accessing the images in an add-in?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach. That makes it part of the file itself. Unless there is some sort of performance issue, I don't see any point in trying to change it.